# specify a path in an array value include?

Tags: php, arrays, include, strtotime

#### how can I include the _counter.txt without semicolon?

```php
  $currentYearPath = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
  $articleCollection = [];
  
  foreach($currentYearPath as $articleDir_name) {
    require $articleDir_name.'/data.php';
    $articleCollection[strtotime($article['date'])] = '
       <div> '.include '/_counter.txt'.' times!</div>
    ';
  }
  krsort($articleCollection);
  echo implode('', $articleCollection);
```

## get an error without semicolon

```
 $articleCollection[strtotime($article['date'])] = '
       <div> '.include '/_counter.txt'.' times!</div>
    ';
```

*Warning: include(…/xx/xx/_counter.txt times! ): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /xx/xx/index.php*

Comment: Are you expecting to save the included file as a string?  Do you want the _file_contents()_?  `implode()` doesn't need a glue declaration/parameter if an empty space is intended.  `array_filter()` is an extra loop.  Just perform the check in the foreach loop.

Comment: @mickmackusa, thanks!  with file_get_contents() works fine!